# How to set default values for edit_post_link() in my theme?

Tags: theme-development, functions, filters

How do I set default values for the `edit_post_link` function in my theme?

I'd like to change the 'Edit This' string to a custom value, but specify this only once, so I can use  instead of  everywhere.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own hook for `edit_post_link` filter:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', 'wpse8170_edit_post_link' );
function wpse8170_edit_post_link( $link ) {
    $matches = array();
    if ( !preg_match( '/\>.*?\<\/a\>/i', $link, $matches ) ) {
        return $link;
    }
    return str_replace( $matches[0], '>MY NEW EDIT LINK TEXT HERE</a>', $link );
}
```